# Is it a good idea to use a combination of cookies and sessions for keeping users logged in

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I am looking at the possibilty to set up a option to keep users logged in. Now I understand a session could be used to allow a user to navigate around without re-entering login information on each page only until the browser is closed and the session is lost. A cookie would be stored client side and has a duration until it expires or the user deletes the cookie.

I was thinking that I could use a combination of both

1. Create a db table (id,user_id,cookie_token,is_active)
2. User logs in which creates a row in the db table connecting the user to the cookie_token which is stored on the client browser (system) as well.

   - Each time a token is created, check to see if the user the token is being created for has any active tokens in the system already and set those to inactive before a new one is created.
   - Only one token can be active per user

So every time the user visits the site, the system looks up that token and checks is_active fields, 
If the user_token is found and is_active = 1 or true, the user data is retrieved (id,name,etc) and this then creates the session and the session variables.

I am not able to find any questions or answers that use a combination of both so it could be that this is just overkill or a very bad idea, I just started to read up on sessions and cookies and have been trying to figure out a system that I could implement myself so would be nice to know if this is good or bad.

Comment: You're heading the right direction, but it's like invalidating the session/log out the user  when the cookie token doesn't exist in the db or is flagged inactive.

Comment: @dnFer this is correct though no? A session cannot be created unless there is a valid cookie token. So no valid cookie token means the user is not logged in. Without a valid token, there is no need to use a session and the website can be browsed as normal without user specific data. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @dnFer Ah I see what you mean, it invalidates the log in if there is an active token in the db table and a new one is created. So before a token is added to the system, check if that user has an active token in the table, set that to inactive before the new one is created. I will edit my question to include this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reply as a comment anymore, because my reply would be too long...
I've implemented something like follows. Unfortunately I can't remember it precisely, but it would give you a pretty good idea:

Visit before manual login:

- Start a session.
- At successful login, store a user identification into this session and store a token value into the dB and into the cookie.

Next time the browser visits the page:

- (re)Start the session.
- Check if a user identification is set in this session.

  - If so, auto-login the user which matches the identification.
  - If not (session expired due time restriction or browser close), check if a token value is stored in the cookie and if this value matches a token value stored in the dB.

    - If an (unexpired) match found, auto-login the user and remove old tokens.
    - If the user identification is invalid and the token value is invalid/expired:

      - logout the user (which contains all actions to go back to "public" mode like destroying the session, removing tokens, cookies, etc.).

Comment: Inspiration from https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Remember_Me

Comment: I'll give this a go. Thanks.